# Defining a bool in Qt pro file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Setting a boolean value for a variable in .pro file can be done the following way:

```
//ProjectFile.pro
DEFINES += "myBool=1"
```

---

This variable can be used in source code *.cpp for conditional compiling. Qt even highlights the conditional expression:
[image]

---

Now Iam looking for a way to use that myBool variable in .pro file

According to Qt documentary conditional statements work like this:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html

```
<condition> {
    <command or definition>
    ...
}
```

---

Outgoing from my very basic qmake knowledge the following approach didnt work

```
//ProjectFile.pro
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {message("Hello from DebugMode")} // => works fine

$$myBool {message("Hello from myBool")} // => not working
```

**Question:** Does somebody know how to handle conditional statements in pro files with a defined variable like myBool?

Comment: FYI: [SO: qmake: using defines as conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34670326/7478597). It seems you cannot evaluate a qmake variable in a condition. At best, you can make new options in `CONFIG`. It seems, they even can have the same name like a variable without interfering.

Comment: FYI: [SO: QMake appending to DEFINE without respecting conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47716470/7478597) Even better: Define the variable depending on the `CONFIG` option to ensure that they are always in sync...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of curiosity, I researched a bit…

First, I consulted [**qmake Manual > Advanced Usage**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html) but that didn't help much.

Then I tried to find something with google and found the following two Q/As (among others):

- [**SO: qmake: using defines as conditionals**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34670326/7478597)
- [**SO: SO: QMake appending to DEFINE without respecting conditional**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47716470/7478597).

I combined what I've found and tested it in my `qmake` (on Debian):

```
CONFIG+=MY_BOOL

MY_BOOL {
  DEFINES+="MY_BOOL=1"
}

message(Defines: $$DEFINES)

MY_BOOL {
  message(MY_BOOL defined)
}
!MY_BOOL {
  message(MY_BOOL not defined)
}
```

Output:

```
Project MESSAGE: Defines: MY_BOOL=1
Project MESSAGE: MY_BOOL defined
```

To counter check, I changed the first line:

```py
#CONFIG+=MY_BOOL
```

Output:

```
Defines: 
Project MESSAGE: MY_BOOL not defined
```